How to retrieve metadata from the Firebase storage
I try to retrieve metadata from the Firebase storage using http get request, but the problem is that I just receive the filename and the bucket. I am using this information for my desktop application which is build on .NET.
public async Task<JArray> ListFilesForUserAsync(string userFolder)
{
     string encodedFolderPath = Uri.EscapeDataString($"{userFolder}/");

     string requestUrl = $"{storageBaseUrl}?prefix={encodedFolderPath}";

     try
     {
         HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUrl);

         if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         {
             string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
             var jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(responseBody);
             var item = (JArray)jsonResponse["items"];
            // GetFileMetadataAsync(userFolder); 
             return item;
         }
         else
         {
             Console.WriteLine($"Error listing files: {response.ReasonPhrase}");
             return null;
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine($"Exception occurred: {ex.Message}");
         return null;
     }
}

I want also to receive more information for each file such as the size, name, last modified.
Can someone help me resolve this problem?

If you want object metadata, you'll have to make a separate API call to get that, much in the same way the client APIs are required to make another call.

what should i change in my new API call to get those information's?
